# create dynamic template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

Hi I want to create angular template dynamically like below:

**Index.html:**

```
    <div ui-view></div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
       <li ng-repeat="item in items">
           <a ui-sref="{{item.id}}"">{{item.name}}</a>
       </li>                    
    </ul>

    <script ng-repeat="item in items" type="text/ng-template" id="{{item.id}}.html">
     <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
    </script>
```

How could I do that? I searched on web and found that we can include template dynamically, but I did not find any place where it is specified that how to create template itself dynamically.

Thanks,
Sombir

Comment: I want to implement Breadcrumbs url scheme, is it possible with directives?

Comment: Yes of course you can. And someone did it http://ncuillery.github.io/angular-breadcrumb yet

Comment: Even if I use directives, I have to use templates and I want the templates to be created dynamically.

Comment: Are you basically asking, how to create html page dynamically. Better use template: add the html elements based on the requirement.

Comment: actually I have many items which are coming from database, and I want to create a new template for each item.

Comment: I think this [dynamicTemplate service](https://github.com/BurakAkyildiz/angularJs-dynamic-conditional-templates) helpfull for this case.

Answer (score 2):

The best way you can do that is Custom Directives! it is what makes angularjs powerfull.

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'myCustomer.html'
  };
});
```

and in your index or whatever you can call it:

```
<my-customer></my-customer>
```

EDIT: 
To generate dynamicaly your Custom directive Use the property Controller or Link.

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'myCustomer.html',
    controller: function ($scope,$http) {
     // here you can use $scope, $http etcs... but
    }, // to make it clean and standard use Link
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      // do all stuff like API call JQuery stuff and all here
    }
  };
});
```

with that you can generate dynamicaly you directive :) from an API or whatever you want to. :)

Comment: Even if I use directives, I have to use templates and I want the templates to be created dynamically.